# How to know which processes open/use a specific semaphore?

Tags: semaphore

We have a semaphore opened by 281 processes, is there any way to get all the pids of these processes?

> ipcs -a|grep 67108878

s   67108878   0xcef73014 --ra-ra----   oracle      dba   oracle      dba   281 17:54:58  9:27:30

Comment: Please reformat your example for readability.  What operating system?  If your system implements SysV IPC in terms of files, the answer probably lies in `lsof` or `pfiles` or `/proc` or similar.  (How would you tell which processes have a regular file open on your system?)

Comment: I am using solaris, but pfiles only shows sockets or files, it doesn't how semaphore. Looks like lsof and /proc doens't have semaphore also.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, using the [Handle.exe utility from SysInternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655), use this syntax:

handle -a SemaphoreName

example for finding the semaphores illustrated in the accepted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7460943/allow-only-3-instances-of-an-application-using-semaphores) on stackoverflow:

```
handle -a \BaseNamedObjects\C15F8F92-2620-4F3C-B8EA-A27285F870DC/myApp
```