# Allow only 3 instances of an application using semaphores

Tags: delphi, semaphore

I am trying to implement a simple routine using semaphores that will allow me to run only 3 instances of the application. I could use 3 mutexes but that is not a nice approach i tried this so far

```
var
  hSem:THandle;
begin
  hSem := CreateSemaphore(nil,3,3,'MySemp3');
  if hSem = 0 then
  begin
    ShowMessage('Application can be run only 3 times at once');
    Halt(1);
  end;
```

How can i do this properly ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Always make sure that you release a semaphore because this is not done automatically if your application dies.

```
program Project72;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Windows,
  SysUtils;

var
  hSem: THandle;

begin
  try
    hSem := CreateSemaphore(nil, 3, 3, 'C15F8F92-2620-4F3C-B8EA-A27285F870DC/myApp');
    Win32Check(hSem <> 0);
    try
      if WaitForSingleObject(hSem, 0) <> WAIT_OBJECT_0 then
        Writeln('Cannot execute, 3 instances already running')
      else begin
        try
          // place your code here
          Writeln('Running, press Enter to stop ...');
          Readln;
        finally ReleaseSemaphore(hSem, 1, nil); end;
      end;
    finally CloseHandle(hSem); end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: +1 Somewhat disappointing that `SyncObjs.TSemaphore` doesn't cater for timed waits. Or did I miss something.

Comment: D2007 doesn't even have SyncObjs.TSemaphore ... In XE, you're correct - one can wait with timeout 0 in Linux but not on Windows. Stupid

Comment: Is the GUID you are using just a way to ensure it is unique? Or is(should) it (be) taken from an identity (logged in user for example)?

Comment: @Marjan, I'm used to using GUIDs for system-wide application-specific identifiers. That way there's a minimal possibility of clashing with identifiers from some other application.

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`TJclAppInstances`](http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JCL_Help:TJclAppInstances) from the [JCL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jcl/).

Answer (score 2):

1. You must try to see if it was created
2. You must use one of the wait function to see if you can get a count
3. At the end, you must release the lock & handle so that it can work the next time user close and open your app

Cheers

```
var
  hSem: THandle;
begin
  hSem := OpenSemaphore(nil, SEMAPHORE_ALL_ACCESS, True, 'MySemp3');
  if hSem = 0 then
    hSem := CreateSemaphore(nil, 3, 3,'MySemp3');

  if hSem = 0 then
  begin
    ShowMessage('... show the error');
    Halt(1);
    Exit;     
  end;

  if WaitForSingleObject(hSem, 0) <> WAIT_OBJECT_0 then
  begin
    CloseHandle(hSem);
    ShowMessage('Application can be runed only 3 times at once');
    Halt(1);
    Exit; 
  end;

  try   
    your application.run codes..

  finally
    ReleaseSemaphore(hSem, 1, nil);
    CloseHandle(hSem);
  end;
```